# How can I add a new block reference for widget instance in Magento?

Tags: magento, widget

When adding a new widget instance in magento (Admin > CMS > Widget Instance)  you need to select layout update for it. In the block reference option, there are several default areas like page top, page bottom, left, right.... How can I add my custom new area to this selection box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Found the answer. Go to `page.xml`, add this

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="custom_script" as="custom_script" translate="label">
    <label>IMPORTANT TO HAVE THIS TAG</label>
</block>
```

The important tag is `<label>`. Without this you won't see the area in selection box. Thank Anthony Nguyen for this.

Comment: Only add this kind of code to your own design files unless you want to lose it when you update Magento.

Comment: Where is `page.xml` located so i can mimic folder structure in my theme?